# Is the ServiceBehavior attribute inherited by another classes?

Tags: c#, wcf, inheritance, attributes

I have several WCF services, and those services share some common methods. So, I have created a base class (not a WCF service) with those methods and made all the WCF services to inherit from this class. Something like this:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    public abstract class BaseService
```

And one of the WCF services:

```
public class ExampleService : BaseService, IExampleService
    {
```

I'm using the ServiceBehavior attribute to set the ConcurrencyMode and InstanceContextMode values, and my question is: Is correct to mark the base class with the ServiceBehavior attribute, and expect all the services to inherit the values of the ServiceBehavior attribute, or should I mark one by one all the WCF services?

Comment: Why not just look at the documentation or inspect the `AttributeUsage` on that attribute?

Comment: Because I haven't found anything about inheritance in the documentation of ServiceBehavior and I don't know how to inspect the AttributeUsage on attributes.But thanks for your RTFM answer. Very useful.

Comment: Nope. And I think that you haven't understood my question at all.

Comment: I understand it perfectly. The `AttributeUsage` only specifies `Class`, hence the `Inherited` property is not set and defaults to false. My point was that you should learn how that attribute (`AttributeUsage`) works.

Comment: Sorry, but I think I'm missing something. If the attribute ussage only specifies Class, and my BaseService Class its an abstract class (not an interface).. why you say that?

Comment: The `ServiceBehavior` attribute is only 'active' on the class you applied it. If, for example, you applied it to your base class, then that could be exposed as a service too, but given you said it is abstract, it will probably not work :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, ServiceBehavior Attribute is inherited to the child classes as the "ServiceBehaviorAttribute" class has the AttributeUsage attribute which doesn't set the "Inherited" value to False.

The default value for "Inherited" is True in "AttributeUsageAttribute" class.

A simple example would be to set the Namespace property in your Abstract class and see that reflected in your wsdl.

Comment: Weird that the default is true. +1 for clarification.

Comment: @leppie If you consider that inheritance is an "is a" relationship then why wouldn't a `Giraffe` inherit all `Animal` attributes?