# Can and how service class inherit from plain class?

Tags: c#, wcf, inheritance, service

I have two services TestService1 and TestService2. Can I inherit both these services from a plain class without ServiceBehaviorAttribute attribute? Like this:

```
public class ServiceBase
{
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class TestService1 : ServiceBase, ITestService1
{
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class TestService2 : ServiceBase, ITestService2
{
}
```

Will the behaviuor from ServiceBehaviorAttribute attribute be applied to inherited members of inherited plain class?

Have I to add some service specific attributtes to base plain class?

If I wrong in realization, how to properly realize such an inheritance - service inherits some behaviour from another plain class?

**UPDATE.**
It is not about [ServiceBehaviorAttribute attribute inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983493/is-the-servicebehavior-attribute-inherited-by-another-classes). I ask more common question - can I inherit some functionality from another class (that is in outside DLL for example, that doesn't even associated with WCF) in WCF service class? And how? Is my code valid and have no concealed nuances?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the ServiceBehavior attribute inherited by another classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983493/is-the-servicebehavior-attribute-inherited-by-another-classes).  Though I'm not sure why you have the same `[ServiceBehavior]` on the derived classes.  Wouldn't you want it on `ServiceBase`

Comment: @MickyD Well, inherits [ServiceBehavior] is an option but not obligatory in my case. I ask more common question - can I inherit some functionality from another class (that is in outside DLL for example, that doesn't even associated with WCF) in WCF service class?

Comment: Sure, `ServiceBase` could have methods that `TestService1` and `TestService2` may utilise. However, WCF clients will only see the methods defined on  your interfaces `ITestService1` and `ITestService2` even if `ServiceBase.SomeMethod()` were `public`.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: @MickyD yes. it is. I want to add some functionality into interior part of services which haven't be seen by clients. If you post it as answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I want to know about concealed difficulties - I asked about additional attributes for base class or something. I have not big experience so I can don't know some small nuances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[ServiceBehavior]` can be applied to base classes such that derived service classes will inherit the behavior.

Change this:

```
public class ServiceBase
{
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class TestService1 : ServiceBase, ITestService1
{
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class TestService2 : ServiceBase, ITestService2
{
}
```

...to this:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class ServiceBase
{
}

public class TestService1 : ServiceBase, ITestService1
{
}

public class TestService2 : ServiceBase, ITestService2
{
}
```

> can I inherit some functionality from another class (that is in outside DLL for example, that doesn't even associated with WCF) in WCF service class?

Sure, `ServiceBase` could have methods that `TestService1` and `TestService2` may utilise. However, WCF clients will only see the methods defined on your interfaces `ITestService1` and `ITestService2` even if `ServiceBase.SomeMethod()` were public.

e.g.

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class ServiceBase
{
    // TestService1 and TestService2  may call me 
    // but not WCF clients. I'm invisible
    public void SomeMethod () {}
}

public class TestService1 : ServiceBase, ITestService1
{
    public void SomeServiceMethod1() { SomeMethod(); }
}

public class TestService2 : ServiceBase, ITestService2
{
    public void SomeServiceMethod2() { SomeMethod(); }
}
```

Regarding your update where the base class is nothing to do with WCF, "yes you can". It's not different to calling any other base class.

Comment: "Regarding your update where the base class is nothing to do with WCF, "yes you can". It's not different to calling any other base class." - So can I leave [ServiceBehavior] in derived classes and leave the base class without this attribute (say it serves another classes that doesn't need [ServiceBehavior] functionality or I just can't change the base class)?

Comment: @Alex34758 That's correct. Your base class can be without any WCF attributes; and be in another assembly.